# Name of a distribution

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have something like

$f(x)=\int_0^{\infty} e^{-kx}x^\alpha(1+x)^\beta dx$

Is this a form of some known distribution?

Comment: Cross-posted at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/373977/is-this-distribution-known.